# VBA eating memory.. cannot clear resources

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a VBA code using xmlHTTP, and I have a problem that I couldn't figure out its reason..

**The problem is:**

while the loop is running it keeps consuming an increasing amount of memory, so I tried to find the part that causes this issue, and I came up with this part:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & "hello" & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responsetext
    DoEvents
Next i
```

I tried everything I can think of (tried to set objects to nothing -inside & outside the loop-, and tried to save the excel file from inside the 'for loop') but I couldn't solve the problem.
I tried the following 3 lines and they are **NOT** fixing anything:

```
    XMLHTTP.abort
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
    Set html = Nothing
```

**Note #1: the problem occurs even when these 11 lines of code are the only code to be executed!**

**Note #2: The memory won't be freed even after the procedure is completed!**

Attached a screenshot of memory usage while the program is running:
[image]

Please advise.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The fix for the issue that Benoit refers to above started rolling out to Office 2016 customers earlier this week. If you don't have the update yet, go to **File** > **Account** > **Update Options** > **Update Now**.

Anneliese from the Office team